# Unit test an external mocked class with constructor parameters in Laravel without creating a factory?

Tags: laravel, unit-testing, laravel-10

In a Laravel unit test we are testing and mocking ReCaptcha\ReCaptcha (and NZTim\Mailchimp\Mailchimp). The working test code is as follows:

```
$this->mock(\ReCaptcha\ReCaptcha::class, function ($mock) use ($mock_response) {
            $mock->shouldReceive('make')
                ->once()
                ->andReturn($mock);
            $mock->shouldReceive('verify')
                ->once()
                ->andReturn($mock_response);
        });
```

In the controller, we have:

```
$recaptcha = app(ReCaptcha::class)->make();
```

To get this to work, as the ReCaptcha class requires a constructor variable, we created the following factory:

```
// ReCaptchaFactory.php

public function make()
{
     $secret = config('services.recaptcha.secret');
     return new ReCaptcha($secret);
}
```

Without the required constructor variable, we can accomplish this with 1 line and remove the extra factory and AppServiceProvider updates:

```
$recaptcha = app(ReCaptcha::class);
```

Something like the following?

```
$recaptcha = resolve(ReCaptcha::class, ['param1'=>config('services.recaptcha.secret'));
```

It just feels like we have a lot of extra unnecessary code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [contextual binding](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/container#contextual-binding) in a service provider:

```
app()->when(ReCaptcha::class)
          ->needs('$secret')
          ->give(config('services.recaptcha.secret');
```

Then in your controller you'd just use:

```
$recaptcha = app(ReCaptcha::class);
```

this will cause your controller to give the recaptcha class the configured secret as it constructs it.

Your test would just need:

```
$this->mock(\ReCaptcha\ReCaptcha::class, function ($mock) use ($mock_response) {
    $mock->shouldReceive('verify')
        ->once()
        ->andReturn($mock_response);
 });
```

this should work because `$this->mock` provides a pre-created (and in this case mocked) instance to the app container so the container will not need to construct a new one and will not need to lookup contextual bindings.